# Write a bookmarklet javascript auto upload file

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, automation, bookmarklet

example I have a form with many `<input>` and `<select>`. Now I dont want to fill all data of form by my hand. So I want to write a bookmarklet javascript to do it. My problem is with normal form tag like `<input>`, `<select>` I can do it easily

```js
document.getElementById("title").value = "Lorem example"
document.getElementById("content").value = "Lorem example"
```

But with input upload file, I confuse how to upload a file automatic without my hand

```
<input type="file" id="bannerImg" />
```

Suppose I have image on path `/Users/MacOs/Downloads/Images/banner_345_308.png`. Is there any way to use javascript to set it for  ?

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely. Functionality like this would be considered a security concern - if you can pre-populate that value, you can hide that file input, get users to click on it, and upload files unintentionally.

Comment: Oh thank for your answer but the problem I can not add hide input because it is online website